# Set up a private Tab in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to know if it is possible to have a tab in a MS Teams Channel that is visible only for those that has access to it, and it is invisible for all other members even if they have access to the channel.

Comment: Tabs setup in a channel will be visible to all the members in the team. You could add [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-flow-tab) to allow showing the contents of the tab to the users who have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Support for private channels is still in WIP. MSFT teams is working hard to bring this feature. As a direct competitor of Slack it has received more than 20K votes but still it is in WIP. Believe it will be out soon. Please check below link. Thanks

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911079-support-for-private-channels